# Best model for inference with non-linear data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, inference

Let’s assume there is a variable $z$ that can be modeled as:

$$z=f(x)+g(y)+ε$$

Where $f$ and $g$ are unknown functions greater than zero, $x$ and $y$ are independent variables and $ε$ is random noise. $y$ is totally unknown, but I have data pairs $(x,z)$ and I’m trying to identify the $x$ value at which $z$ is “considerably” influenced by $f(x)$. "considerably influenced" means something like finding $x_1$ at which the expected value of $z$ change certain predefined amount. That is, finding $x_1$ such that:
$$E[z|x = x_1] - E[z|x = x_0] > C$$

for some predefined reference point $x_0$ (which can be some low value of $x$) and threshold $C$.
I can assume that $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing. An example of the relationship between $x$ and $z$ could be this:

[image: x vs z]

Qualitatively, this point might be somewhere above $x=20$, but I’d like to have a formal approach using well defined and repeatable criteria. I was thinking on fitting a model $\hat{z}=h(x)$ and find $x_1$ at which $Δh=h(x_1)-h(x_{0})=C$ so the problem can be easily solved if $x_{0}$ and $C$ are defined.
My question is what type of model would be suitable and whether the heteroscedasticity of the data makes this approach invalid.

Any suggestions and critics to my approach are also appreciated.

Comment: What’s up with the two error terms? Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: @Dave perhaps having two different error terms might be confusing, so I left just one. I have no additional information regarding this error term. But I assume it must exists. Basically I'm saying that the scatter at any $x$ value comes from the unknown function $g(y)>0$ and from another random (perhaps normally distributed) term.

Comment: It would help to have a clear characterization of what you mean by "considerably influenced."

Comment: @whuber I edited the question to clarify